# Could not find a declaration file for module in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

working with Vue js 3 and Laravel 8 project. in the project installed via npm vue editor js package as following. https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/vue-editor-js and I have following app.js file
app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import router from './router'
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import mainapp from './components/mainapp.vue';
import common from './common'
import store from './store'
import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index'


createApp({
    components: {
        mainapp,
        
        },
    
}).use(router).use(store).use(ViewUIPlus).use(Editor).mixin(common).mount('#app');
```

import file `import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index'` generated following error message

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-editor-js/src/index'. 'F:/2021 Technics/vue + laravel/vue 3/fullstack/node_modules/vue-editor-js/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-editor-js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index';
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to do what the system suggests? Which results?

Comment: No suggestion above warning encounting

Comment: I mean: do from a terminal: `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-editor-js` ? If this answers not found, create a file named `vue-editor-js.d.ts` containing the line: `declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index`

Comment: @SiliconValley could you explain in details how to create file like your comment `vue-editor-js.d.ts containing the line: declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index`